# Long to void* casting in pThreads

Tags: c, pthreads

From the code shown below:
I don't understand how the pthread_create function can cast thread which is of type long to type void*. I know that it is the format of the function however, long is an integer data type while void* is a pointer type.

Thank you,

```
int main() {
    long thread;
    pthread_t* thread_handles;
    ready =0;
    /* create an array of thread handles */
    thread_handles = malloc (thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t));

    /* start the threads, giving each a unique rank */
    for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL,
          Hello, (void*) thread);
    }

    /* print a message from the main thread */
    printf("Hello from the main thread\n");
    

    /* wait for all threads to complete */
    for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    }

   /* delete the array of thread handles */
   free(thread_handles);

   return 0;
}
```

I have researched online on sites such as https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-pthread-create-create-thread
However, it doesn't mention the why behind it. I know that it is the format but casting shouldn't work?

Comment: You can cast an integer to a pointer and then back to an integer (this part is presumably done in the Hello function). The result may be implementation specific, but on most common platforms you will get your original integer back. The intermediate pointer is not pointing to anything, it acts as a container to store an integer.

Comment: It may not work if `sizeof(long) > sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: `uintptr_t` would make more sense than `long` here.

Comment: It's a trick that should work on most implementations, but is not guaranteed to work by POSIX. One way to avoid the trick and still avoid allocating any more memory is to give the `thread_handles` variable file or global level scope and to use `&thread_handles[thread]` as the final parameter of `pthread_create()`. Then the thread can do a bit of simple pointer arithmetic to recover the value of `thread`.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, @chux-ReinstateMonica.  One needs an integer type *small enough* to be conveyable in the form of a `void *` without loss of fidelity.  But `uintptr_t` gives you the opposite: an integer type *large enough* that it can convey a `void *` without loss of fidelity.  `uintptr_t` can be wider than `void *`, which is exactly what you want to avoid.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Fair point.   Although `(u)intptr_t` might be larger than needed, `long` has the same issue and so not a better alterative.  From a industry POV, I have never come across an implementation where `(u)intptr_t` is wider than `void *`, yet I have seen `long` wider than `void *`.  `size_t` might be an alterative of a wide-ish integer type yet certainly not wider than a `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this question should be a dupe, but I haven't found quite the right target, so I'm just going to answer.

> I don't understand how the pthread_create function can cast thread which is of type long to type void*.

`pthread_create()` is not doing any such thing.  *Its caller*, the program's `main()`, is performing the conversion.  And as for how, you apparently already recognize that it is using a cast operator.

I guess the real question comes down to this ...

> casting shouldn't work [in this case]?

... and the answer is it *should* work.  The language specification explicitly says so:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type.

(C17 6.3.2.3/5)

However,

> Except [for an
> integer constant expression with value 0], the result is
> implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not
> point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap
> representation.

, so it is not without risk, including that it might not be suitable for every representable integer value.

And note too that the resulting pointer value does not actually point to any object, unless by accident.  It must be assumed to be an invalid pointer.

C also provides for pointers to be converted to integers, which is presumably what the thread function will do with its argument in your example. Although neither the C language nor POSIX guarantees that integers can be conveyed unchanged via pointers in this way, in practice, it works reliably on a wide variety of systems as long as the values to be conveyed are within some reasonably generous implementation-specific range.

Overall, the practice of passing integers to functions via conversion through a pointer type sees relatively wide use in conjunction with `pthread_create()`, but otherwise it is relatively rare.

Answer (score -1):

Pointer is natively integer value, that holds address in memory. So it's no problem for compiler to cast long to pointer.

Comment: It's not the compiler that allows the cast, it's C standard.

As per C17 standard 6.3.2.3, an integer may be converted to any pointer type, and any pointer type may be converted to an integer type, but results of this conversion (except integer `0`) are implementation-defined. There's nothing said about any addresses.

Comment: @SergeS, "it's no problem for compiler to cast long to pointer." --> Problems include: "... the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."

Comment: @Sergej Christoforov "Implementation-defined" is not UB.  We can always check details about this conversion for specific compiler:  (gcc)[https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation]. 
It's not portable, but its' well known practice and the tons of code do such conversions, Glib for example.
As per C17 standard  you can check also 7.20.1.4 (uintptr_t) to be sure that it's possible.